# Couldn't find User with id=1

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've a `current_user` method to handle authentication.

**application_controller.rb**

```
protect_from_forgery
helper_method :current_user

def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

but when I try to acces a to a page I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=1
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10:in `current_user'
```

How can I pass `@current_user` a sort of default value so if there's no user it will redirect to login page.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your session contains old data, specifically an id (1) of a user which no longer exists. Try handling the `RecordNotFound` exception raised by ActiveRecord, and returning nil:

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end
```

To redirect, you should add a second `before_filter` which checks for a user and handles redirecting to the login path:

```
before_filter :require_user

def require_user
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user
end
```

Remember to omit `require_user` for your login action by adding `skip_before_filter :require_login` to whichever controller manages your authentication.

Comment: Thans for helping.I guess that old data comes from a migration mess I've reset migration multiple times.