# "missing required keys" - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following Controller called Login:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :require_user
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  end

  def require_user
    redirect_to login_path unless current_user
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Você foi deslogado"
  end

  def create
    user = User.validate(login_params[:email], login_params[:senha])
    if user
      session[:user] = user.id
      redirect_to "/home/inicio", notice: "login feito com sucesso"
    else
      redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Dados incorretos"
    end
  end

  private

  def login_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :senha)
  end
end
```

and this is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'login#new'
  get '/home/inicio', to: 'home#index'

  scope '/login' do
    get '/acesso', to:'login#new'
    post '/acessorecebendo', to:'login#create'
    get '/sair', to:'login#destroy'
  end

  resources :login
  resources :home
  resources :produtos
  resources :fornecedors
end
```

and the error:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"login"}, missing
>   required keys: [:id]

at the lines:

```
def require_user
  redirect_to login_path unless current_user   
end
```

the point is: if I delete the line "**before_action :...**" found in Login controller, I got this error:

> Couldn't find User with 'id'=2

the new.html.erb (the login's view):

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div> 
<% end %>

<div class="login-page">   
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="Senha"/>
      <button>Cadastrar</button>
      <p class="message">Já é registrado? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Não está registrado <a href="#">Criar uma conta</a></p>
    </form>
    <% if session[:user] %>
      <a href="/login/sair">Sair sessão <%= @user.nome %> </a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, to try solve this, I need to do a way to check if are someone logged or not and redirect to the proper view. I'm trying do something like that with this before action...

can someone explain this to me, please? :\

I tried to follow this solutions: [Couldn't find User with id=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526082/couldnt-find-user-with-id-1)

But it didn't work..

Comment: Could you add the view which redirects you to the show method?

Comment: What view? The problem is on the before_action method :\

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i putted the view of login controller

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this:

```
redirect_to login_path unless current_user
```

Is that `login_path` requires and `id`, which you can see by running `rake routes` in the console:

```
           acesso GET    /login/acesso(.:format)          login#new
  acessorecebendo POST   /login/acessorecebendo(.:format) login#create
             sair GET    /login/sair(.:format)            login#destroy
      login_index GET    /login(.:format)                 login#index
                  POST   /login(.:format)                 login#create
        new_login GET    /login/new(.:format)             login#new
       edit_login GET    /login/:id/edit(.:format)        login#edit
            login GET    /login/:id(.:format)             login#show
                  PATCH  /login/:id(.:format)             login#update
                  PUT    /login/:id(.:format)             login#update
                  DELETE /login/:id(.:format)             login#destroy
       home_index GET    /home(.:format)                  home#index
                  POST   /home(.:format)                  home#create
         new_home GET    /home/new(.:format)              home#new
        edit_home GET    /home/:id/edit(.:format)         home#edit
                  GET    /home/:id(.:format)              home#show
                  PATCH  /home/:id(.:format)              home#update
                  PUT    /home/:id(.:format)              home#update
                  DELETE /home/:id(.:format)              home#destroy
```

(I removed some for brevity's sake.)

I'm guessing you probably want to do:

```
redirect_to accesso_path unless current_user
```

Or, possibly:

```
redirect_to new_login_path unless current_user
```

They both point to the same place, by the way, so you probably can get rid of `accesso_path` and replace it with `login_new`.

So, the other problem is sounds like you are likely having (from your comments), is that you have a invalid `id` in `session[:user_id]`. When you remove `before_action :require_user`, then, you're getting to:

```
def new
  if session[:user]
    @user = User.find(session[:user])
  end
end
```

Which is then raising the exception:

> Couldn't find User with 'id'=2

So, here's probably what you should do:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  protect_from_forgery
  before_action :go_home_if_signed_in
  helper_method :current_user
  # ^^^
  # I don't know what this is


  def go_home_if_signed_in
    if session[:user_id]
      # there was a session[:user_id]
      # use find_by instead of find because it won't raise an exception
      if User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        # the session[:user_id] resulted in a valid user, so
        # send the user to their home page.
        redirect_to home_index_path
      else
        # if the User wasn't found, then you'll be in here, without
        # raising an exception.
        # So now you want to set the session[:user_id] to nil
        # because it's invalid.
        session[:user_id] = nil
      end
    end
  end

  # you should be able to get rid of this.
  # def require_user
  #   redirect_to new_login_path unless current_user # or wherever, but not login_path
  # end

  def show

  end

  def new
    # This seems wrong. What is session[:user] and how do you 
    # expect User to find it?
    # if session[:user]
    #   @user = User.find(session[:user])
    # end
  end

  def destroy
    # Make sure you set session[:user] = nil somewhere!!!
    reset_session
    # ^^^
    # I don't know what this is.
    # redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Você foi deslogado"
    redirect_to :acesso_path, notice: "Você foi deslogado"
    # ^^^
    # Why not use the path you generated in routes? You went through
    # the trouble of defining it.
  end

  def create
    user = User.validate(login_params[:email], login_params[:senha])
    if user
      session[:user] = user.id
      redirect_to "/home/inicio", notice: "login feito com sucesso"
    else
      redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Dados incorretos"
    end
  end

  private

  def login_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :senha)
  end
end
```

Comment: i dont have any method called accesso_path or login_new. this doesnt exists here )=

Comment: No. Those are path names. Look at the output of `rake routes` that I pasted above (line 1 and line 6). Like I said, you are trying to `redirect_to` `login_path` and that path requires and `id` (line 8). By the way, I got the path name slightly wrong for `new_login_path` and I just corrected it.

Comment: I understand that but how can i "clear" the cache from this? i mean, if i delete the before_ation and helper_method also both methods too, i got this error:

Couldn't find User with 'id'=2

at the line:

  def new
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

Comment: This doesnt make sense to me cus the id=2 is the last id i had tested before deleted it from the table at DB.

Comment: @jvillian is ok with his answer. You have to read more about rails routing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html